# Delphi Indy 10 Demo Application Client Server

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

This code is based on an demo application from source forge using indy10 with delphi xe or delphi 2010. i tried to add some improvements , but now the clients hangs up while exchanging data  with the server

```
> procedure TServerMainForm.**IdTCPServerExecute(AContext:
> TIdContext);** var   LBuffer: TBytes;
> 
>   LSize: LongInt;
> 
>   CMD_CLASS: Integer;   line: String;
> 
>   aMs: TMemoryStream;
> 
>   aINDYCMD: TGenericRecord<TINDYCMD>;   aMyRecord:
> TGenericRecord<TMyRecord>;
> 
> begin
> 
>   aINDYCMD := TGenericRecord<TINDYCMD>.Create;   aMyRecord :=
> TGenericRecord<TMyRecord>.Create;
> 
>   AIndyRecord_TS := TINDYCMDThreadSafeRecord.Create;   // NEW THREAD
> SAVE RECORDE.. IF I NEED VCL ACCESS !!!   aMyRecord_TS :=
> TMyRECORDThreadSafeRecord.CReate;
> 
> 
> 
>   AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 90000;
> 
>   // 'server execute start'
> 
>   if (ReceiveBuffer(AContext, LBuffer) = False) then   begin
>     TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowCannotGetDataErrorMessage);
>     Exit;   end   else   begin
>     TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowDataReceivedMessage);
> 
>     aINDYCMD.value := aINDYCMD.ByteArrayToMyRecord(LBuffer);
> 
>     AIndyRecord_TS.lock;
> 
>     AIndyRecord_TS.value := aINDYCMD.value;
> 
>     //  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(RecordReceived_TMyRecord);      BUGGY CODE I GUESS
>     // TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(RecordReceived_TINDY_CMD);
>     AIndyRecord_TS.unlock;
> 
>   end;
> 
>   aINDYCMD.value := aINDYCMD.ByteArrayToMyRecord(LBuffer);
> 
> 
>   CMD_CLASS := aINDYCMD.value.CMD_CLASS;
> 
>   // MainStatusBar.SimpleText := ' CMD_CLASS -> ' + 
> INtToStr(aINDYCMD.value.CMD_CLASS);
> 
>   case CMD_CLASS of
>     0:
>       begin
>         /// receive a simple string from client
>         line := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('');
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('CLIENT STRING -> ' + line);
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('');
>       end;
> 
>     1:
>       begin
>         ///
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('');
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('SEND RECORD BACK TO CLIENT#1');
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('');
> 
>         AIndyRecord_TS.lock;
>         AIndyRecord_TS.value.CMD_TIMESTAMP := now;
>         AIndyRecord_TS.value.CMD_VALUE := ' TEST SEND BACK SERVER TIME -> ' +
>           dateToStr(now) + '/' + TimeToStr(now);
>         AIndyRecord_TS.value.CMD_CLASS := 100;
>         aINDYCMD.value := AIndyRecord_TS.value;
>         AIndyRecord_TS.unlock;
> 
>         LBuffer := aINDYCMD.MyRecordToByteArray(aINDYCMD.value);
> 
>         if (SendBuffer(AContext, LBuffer) = False) then
>         begin
>           TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowCannotSendDataErrorMessage);
>         end
>         else
>         begin
>           TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowDataSendMessage);
>         end;
>       end;
>     2:
>       begin
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('');
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('SEND RECORD BACK TO CLIENT#2');
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('');
>         aMyRecord_TS.value.Details := ' complex server response ......';
>         aMyRecord_TS.value.FileName := 'TEXT TEST TEXT TEST';
>         aMyRecord_TS.value.FileDate := now;
>         aMyRecord_TS.value.Recordsize := Random(100);
>         aMyRecord_TS.value.FileSize := 1234567890;
> 
>         aMyRecord.value := aMyRecord.value;
> 
>         LBuffer := aMyRecord.MyRecordToByteArray(aMyRecord.value);
> 
>         if (SendBuffer(AContext, LBuffer) = False) then
>         begin
>           TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowCannotSendDataErrorMessage);
>         end
>         else
>         begin
>           TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowDataSendMessage);
>         end;
> 
>       end;
> 
>     3:
>       begin
>         ///
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('record received, paint random record !');
> 
>         abmp.Height := 300;
>         abmp.Width := 300;
> 
>         DrawRandomBitMap(abmp);
> 
>         ServerImage.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(abmp);
> 
>       end;
>     4:
>       begin
>         ///
>         // Memo1.Lines.Add('send stream back !');
>         ///
>         aMs := TMemoryStream.Create;
>         abmp.SaveToStream(aMs);
> 
>         if (SendStream(AContext, TStream(aMs)) = False) then
>         begin
>           TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowCannotSendStreamDataErrorMessage);
>           Exit;
>         end;
> 
>         aMs.Free;
> 
>       end;
> 
>   else
>     //   end;
> 
>   LEDShape.brush.Color := clgreen;
> 
>   // Memo1.Lines.Add('server execute done');
> 
>   aINDYCMD.Free;   aMyRecord.Free;
> 
>   AIndyRecord_TS.Free;   aMyRecord_TS.Free;
> 
> end;
> 
> procedure TServerMainForm.DrawRandomBitMap(aBitMap: TBitMap); var   i,
> j: Integer;   rx1, rx2: Integer;   ry1, ry2: Integer;   w, h: Integer;
> 
> begin   w := aBitMap.Width;   h := aBitMap.Height;
> 
>   abmp.Canvas.FloodFill(0, 0, clwhite, fsSurface);
> 
>   for i := 1 to 30 do   begin
> 
>     randomize;
> 
>     rx1 := Random(w - 1);
>     rx2 := Random(w - 1);
> 
>     ry1 := Random(h - 1);
>     ry2 := Random(h - 1);
> 
>     aBitMap.Canvas.Pen.Color := RandomColor;
> 
>     aBitMap.Canvas.MoveTo(rx1, ry1);
> 
>     aBitMap.Canvas.LineTo(rx2, ry2);
> 
>   end;
> 
> end;

procedure TServerMainForm.RecordReceived_TINDY_CMD;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('------------------< RECORD VALUES >-------------');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(' CMD_Value -> ' + AIndyRecord_TS.value.CMD_VALUE);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(' CMD_CLASS -> ' + INtToStr(AIndyRecord_TS.value.CMD_CLASS));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(' CMD_CLASS -> ' +
    dateToStr(AIndyRecord_TS.value.CMD_TIMESTAMP));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('--------------------< END >----------------------')
end;

procedure TServerMainForm.RecordReceived_TMyRecord;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('--------------------< RECORD VALUES >----------------');
  // Memo1.Lines.Add('Details ' + aMyRecord.value.Details);
  // Memo1.Lines.Add('FileName = ' + aMyRecord.value.FileName);
  // Memo1.Lines.Add('FileSize = ' + INtToStr(aMyRecord.value.FileSize));
  // Memo1.Lines.Add('RecordSize = ' + INtToStr(aMyRecord.value.Recordsize));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('--------------------< END >------------------------')
end;

///
/// ...
///
procedure TServerMainForm.ServerActiveCheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer.Active := ServerActiveCheckBox.Checked;

  if IdTCPServer.Active then
    LEDShape.brush.Color := clgreen
  else
    LEDShape.brush.Color := clred;

end;

///
/// not yet implemented  ....
///
procedure TServerMainForm.ServerBindingsButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  SocketHandle: TIDSocketHandles;
begin

  // binding set to 127.0.0.1   ::  50000

  IdTCPServer.Active := False;

  IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  // else, throw socket error # 98 , address already in use ...
  IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add.IP := IPEdit.text; // '127.0.0.1';
  IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add.Port := StrToInt(PortEdit.text); // 5000;

  // customization
  ServerActiveCheckBox.Checked := true;
  IdTCPServer.Active := ServerActiveCheckBox.Checked;

  //
  MainStatusBar.SimpleText := 'server running on port ' + PortEdit.text +
    ' host ip ->' + IPEdit.text;

end;

///
/// get all available IP's
///
procedure TServerMainForm.PopolateIPLIstButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MYIdStack: TIdStack;
begin

  /// methode #1  , working with INDY IDIPWatch
  IdIPWatch.Active := true;
  MainStatusBar.SimpleText := IdIPWatch.LocalIP + '...' + IdIPWatch.CurrentIP;

  /// meathode #2 , see ....

  with IPListCheckListBox do
  begin
    Clear;
    Items := GStack.LocalAddresses;
    If IPListCheckListBox.Items.Strings[0] <> '127.0.0.1' then
      Items.Insert(0, '127.0.0.1');

    Checked[0] := true;

  end;

end;

procedure TServerMainForm.ShowDataReceivedMessage;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Data received' + TimeToStr(now));
end;

procedure TServerMainForm.ShowDataSendMessage;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Data send' + TimeToStr(now));
end;

procedure TServerMainForm.ShowCannotGetDataErrorMessage;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Cannot get data from client, Unknown error occured' +
    TimeToStr(now));
end;

procedure TServerMainForm.ShowCannotSendDataErrorMessage;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Cannot send data to client, Unknown error occured' +
    TimeToStr(now));
end;

procedure TServerMainForm.ShowCannotSendStreamDataErrorMessage;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Cannot send STREAM data to client, Unknown error occured' +
    TimeToStr(now));
end;

procedure TServerMainForm.IdTCPServerException(AContext: TIdContext;
  AException: Exception);
begin
  with AContext.Connection.IOHandler do
  begin
    writeln('server.exception' + TimeToStr(now));
  end;
end;

end.
```

The relevant client code is also changed in respect to the original version on source forge see the client stuff here

```
/// selct a command from a CMD List box, today only trial code
procedure TIndyClientMainForm.ClientExecuteButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  aINDYCMD: TGenericRecord<TINDYCMD>;
  aINDYCMD_temp: TINDYCMD;
  aMyRecord: TGenericRecord<TMyRecord>;
  aMyRecord_temp: TMyRecord;
  CmdIndex: Integer;
  line: String;
  LBuffer: TBytes;

  aMemStream: TMemoryStream;
begin


  /// very simple record type to send to the server

  aINDYCMD := TGenericRecord<TINDYCMD>.Create;

  aMyRecord := TGenericRecord<TMyRecord>.Create;


  CmdIndex := CommandComboBox.ItemIndex;

  // Memo1.Lines.Add('start client execute : ' + IntToStr(CmdIndex));

  MakeINDYCommand(aINDYCMD_temp, CmdIndex);
  aINDYCMD.Value := aINDYCMD_temp;

  MakeMyRecord(aMyRecord_temp);
  aMyRecord.Value := aMyRecord_temp;

  /// start   communication client server .....

  LBuffer := aINDYCMD.MyRecordToByteArray(aINDYCMD.Value);
  if (SendBuffer(MyIdTCPClient, LBuffer) = false) then
  begin
     TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowCannotSendDataErrorMessage);
  end
  else
  begin
     TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowDataSendMessage);
  end;

  case CmdIndex of
    0:
      /// send a string tp the server
      begin
        ///  'send text  ;
        MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn(SendTextEdit.Text);
        TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowDataSendMessage);
      end;
    1:
      /// send INDY CMD and get INDY CMD from the server
      begin

        ///
        ///
        if ( NOT ReceiveBuffer(MyIdTCPClient, LBuffer)) then
        begin
              // 'Cannot receive record/buffer from server.'
              TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowCannotGetDataErrorMessage);
        end
        else
        begin
          aINDYCMD.Value := aINDYCMD.ByteArrayToMyRecord(LBuffer);
          //  ShowCMDRecord('ServerResponse', aINDYCMD.Value);
           TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowDataReceivedMessage);
        end;
      end;
    2:
      /// send INDY RECORD GET CLIENTSVR RECORD from server
      begin
        ///
        ///
        if (NOT ReceiveBuffer(MyIdTCPClient, LBuffer)) then
        begin
         // 'Cannot receive record/buffer from server.'
          TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowCannotGetDataErrorMessage);
        end
        else
        begin
          aMyRecord.Value := aMyRecord.ByteArrayToMyRecord(LBuffer);
           TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ShowDataReceivedMessage);
          // ShowDataRecord('ServerResponse', aMyRecord.Value);
        end;
      end;

    3:

      begin
        /// do nothing !!!!!!!
      end;
    4:
      /// get a file from the server
      begin
        /// *   todo  !!!!
        ///
        ///
        ///
        aMemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

        if (ReceiveStream(MyIdTCPClient, TStream(aMemStream)) = false) then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add
            ('Cannot get STREAM from server, Unknown error occured');
          Exit;
        end;

        ClientImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(TStream(aMemStream));

        aMemStream.Free;

      end
  else
    ///
  end;

  aINDYCMD.Free;

  aMyRecord.Free;



end;
```

I have no clue why the client now hangs up after sendind the record to the server ??
the server says his is fine with sendinding the record up actually the client is frozen

For reference the helper indy wrapper functions

```
///
/// -------------   HELPER FUNCTION FOR RECORD EXCHANGE   ---------------------
///

function ReceiveBuffer(AClient: TIdTCPClient; var ABuffer: TBytes)
  : Boolean; overload;
var
  LSize: LongInt;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    LSize := AClient.IOHandler.ReadLongInt();
    AClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(ABuffer, LSize, False);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function SendBuffer(AClient: TIdTCPClient; ABuffer: TBytes): Boolean; overload;
begin
  try
    Result := True;
    try
      AClient.IOHandler.Write(LongInt(Length(ABuffer)));
      AClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
      AClient.IOHandler.Write(ABuffer, Length(ABuffer));
      AClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferFlush;
    finally
      AClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;

end;

function SendBuffer(AContext: TIdContext; ABuffer: TBytes): Boolean; overload;
begin
  try
    Result := True;
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(LongInt(Length(ABuffer)));
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ABuffer, Length(ABuffer));
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferFlush;
    finally
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function ReceiveBuffer(AContext: TIdContext; var ABuffer: TBytes)
  : Boolean; overload;
var
  LSize: LongInt;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    LSize := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongInt();
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(ABuffer, LSize, False);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

///
/// ---------------------   HELP FUNCTION FOR STREAM  EXCHANGE  --------------
///

function ReceiveStream(AContext: TIdContext; var AStream: TStream)
  : Boolean; overload;
var
  LSize: LongInt;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    LSize := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongInt();
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, LSize, False);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function ReceiveStream(AClient: TIdTCPClient; var AStream: TStream)
  : Boolean; overload;
var
  LSize: LongInt;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    LSize := AClient.IOHandler.ReadLongInt();
    AClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, LSize, False);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function SendStream(AContext: TIdContext; AStream: TStream): Boolean; overload;
var
  StreamSize: LongInt;
begin
  try
    Result := True;
    try
      StreamSize := (AStream.Size);

      // AStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(LongInt(StreamSize));
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(AStream, 0, False);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferFlush;
    finally
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;

end;

function SendStream(AClient: TIdTCPClient; AStream: TStream): Boolean; overload;
var
  StreamSize: LongInt;
begin
  try
    Result := True;
    try
      StreamSize := (AStream.Size);

      // AStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      // AClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      // AClient.IOHandler.SendBufferSize := 32768;

      AClient.IOHandler.Write(LongInt(StreamSize));
      AClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
      AClient.IOHandler.Write(AStream, 0, False);
      AClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferFlush;
    finally
      AClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

///
/// ---------------      HELPER FUNCTIONS FOR FILES EXCHANGE  ----------------
///
function ClientSendFile(AClient: TIdTCPClient; Filename: String): Boolean;
begin

  AClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True; // fully support large streams
  Result := True;
  try
    AClient.IOHandler.WriteFile(Filename); // send file stream data
  except
    Result := False;
  end;

end;

function ClientReceiveFile(AClient: TIdTCPClient; Filename: String): Boolean;
begin

  /// todo ......

end;

function ServerSendFile(AContext: TIdContext; Filename: String): Boolean;
begin

  /// todo ......

end;

function ServerReceiveFile(AContext: TIdContext; ServerFilename: String;
  var ClientFilename: String): Boolean;
var
  // LSize: String;
  AStream: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    Result := True;
    AStream := TFileStream.Create(ServerFilename, fmCreate + fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(AStream);
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

///
/// ---------------   HELPER FUNCTION FOR RECORD EXCHANGE  ------------------
/// (not using generic syntax features of DELPHI 2009 and better )

function MyRecordToByteArray(aRecord: TMyRecord): TBytes;
var
  LSource: PAnsiChar;
begin
  LSource := PAnsiChar(@aRecord);
  SetLength(Result, SizeOf(TMyRecord));
  Move(LSource[0], Result[0], SizeOf(TMyRecord));
end;

function ByteArrayToMyRecord(ABuffer: TBytes): TMyRecord;
var
  LDest: PAnsiChar;
begin
  LDest := PAnsiChar(@Result);
  Move(ABuffer[0], LDest[0], SizeOf(TMyRecord));
end;

function TGenericRecord<TRecordType>.MyRecordToByteArray
  (aRecord: TRecordType): TBytes;
var
  LSource: PAnsiChar;
begin
  LSource := PAnsiChar(@aRecord);
  SetLength(Result, SizeOf(TRecordType));
  Move(LSource[0], Result[0], SizeOf(TRecordType));
end;

function TGenericRecord<TRecordType>.ByteArrayToMyRecord(ABuffer: TBytes)
  : TRecordType;
var
  LDest: PAnsiChar;
begin
  LDest := PAnsiChar(@Result);
  Move(ABuffer[0], LDest[0], SizeOf(TRecordType));
end;
```

Comment: in the original code all memo1.lines. ...  statements have been remved from the server.execute , I guess that has been the reason why the server has a hang up (VCL is not THREAD SAVE)

Comment: still playing around with the code - guess the server does not send back data -- but do not have any real idea why this code fails ... need any help !

Comment: If the code worked, but it fails after your changes, then you *do* have a real idea of why it fails. It fails because of something you added. Remove your changes, and then start adding them back until it fails again. Then you'll have your answer. [Nobody wants to read all that code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/33732) just to find the bug you introduced yourself. When you identify the change you made, you can ask "Why does this specific change cause this specific behavior?" Posting a link to the original code would be helpful, too.

Comment: also the original code seem to have a similar bug as my version, see https://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/  for the originl code. if you check all other samples they work ... only sample 3 show that strange bug, but I need to continue with sample 3

Comment: I work on the Indy development team, and even I don't want to have to (or even have the time to) sit through all that code trying to figure out what it is doing, let alone why it is failing. You will have a better chance of getting help if you reduce the code to a bare-bones example that reproduces the same issue.

Comment: Ok , already many people download this code - there are no better / more complete/complex  demo samples from INDY 10 TCP client server. please have a look on http://indy10clieservr.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/indy10clieservr/Shared/Unit_Indy_Functions.pas?revision=91&view=markup -is there something wrong with that code in principal ?

Comment: may be I can reduce your work -  just getting some inputs from you on my questions .. than later trigger BDLM (the owner od the source forge project) to update his samples